# How to get rid of stroke lines between cells in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I've been experimenting with D3 for a few days and one of things I could not figure out hot to do, is how to get rid of the the strokes between the cells. My first though was to scale them up a bit, but I can't seem to make it work. Is there any way to get rid of them at all, using some built-in method?

```js
   const generateSvgNode = (width, height) => {
  const svg = d3.create("svg").attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])

  const g = svg.append("g");

  const points = d3.range(200).map(function() {
        return [
              Math.random() * width,
              Math.random() * height
        ];
  });

  const delaunay = d3.Delaunay.from(points)
  const voronoi = delaunay.voronoi([0.5, 0.5, width - 0.5, height - 0.5])
  const polygons = voronoi.cellPolygons() 

  const palette = ['#8EB338', '#9DBF3E', '#9BBD3D', '#94B93B', '#9EC03F', '#97BB3B', '#94B93B', '#9EC03F', '#9EC03F', '#9BBD3D', '#A6C542', '#93B83A', '#92B73A', '#9ABE3D', '#96B93B', '#90B439', '#97BB3B', '#93B73B', '#9EC03F', '#97BA3C', '#90B439', '#A1C140', '#9BBD3D', '#90B239', '#95BA3B', '#9EC03F', '#A2C241', '#8FB339', '#93B83A', '#A2C241']


  g.selectAll("path")
    .data(polygons)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", (d) => `M${d.join("L")}Z`)
    .attr('fill', (d, i) => palette[Math.floor(Math.random()*palette.length)])
    .attr("stroke", 'none')

  

  return svg.node()
}


const onResize = () => {
  document.querySelector('svg').remove();

  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  const svg = generateSvgNode(width, height)
  document.body.appendChild(svg);
}

const onLoad = () => {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  const svg = generateSvgNode(width, height)
  document.body.appendChild(svg);
}

window.onload = onLoad;
window.onresize = onResize;
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is enough, but adding a stroke to the `path`s already gets rid of most of the strokes. I assume the remainder is mostly due to rounding errors or anti-aliasing issues in the rendering.

Comment: The snippet does not work

Comment: It's the background of the svg that you're seeing. Don't think you can remove that. Using the same color is probably your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround we can set stroke colour to be the same as fill colour, then stroke lines will be indistinguishable. For that we may generate colours deterministically (or alternatively store them for each polygon)

E.g.:

```
const colorGetter = (d,i) => palette[( i + Math.floor((d[0][0] * d[1][1])*1000) ) % palette.length]
  
g.selectAll("path")
    .data(polygons)
    ...
    .attr("fill", colorGetter)
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("stroke", colorGetter)
```

Comment: I think that would work for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is this bit of css:

```
path {
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

That will get rid of the "stroke" (rather, anti-aliasing artefacts) - it does come at the cost of looking a little pixelly on some boundaries but since your colour scheme is a graduation of just the one hue it's not that noticeable